# WooCommerce Shipping Totals work on frontend but not backend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On my company's WooCommerce website, shipping calculation works on the front-end (customer facing) but not the backend (when manually placing call-in orders).

The address is put in. I've tried adding shipping classes and default shipping rates to the products, but this does not help. The shipping total stays at 0.00 unless I manually put in an amount by adding it manually through meta.

For now, we're using the customer-facing cart system, but it would be really nice to utilize the backend for placing orders like you should be able to.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOFdq.jpg)

Comment: Could we see the code that's at fault? Or that you believe is at fault?

Comment: It's really just the default WooCommerce cart with the Weight Based Shipping plugin. I added auto complete paid orders: `function auto_update_orders_status_from_processing_to_completed(){
    // Get all current "processing" customer orders
    $processing_orders = wc_get_orders( $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'wc-processing',
    ) );
    if(!empty($processing_orders))
        foreach($processing_orders as $order)
            $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'auto_update_orders_status_from_processing_to_completed' );`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, WooCommerce **does not** calculate shipping quotes in backend by design. Many users suggested that feature, but unfortunately no ETA yet. See https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/17238

If you need this now, you have to buy a commercial plug-in, as there are many offering exactly such feature. You should search a WooCommerce plug-in for "manual orders" or "phone orders".